# using one directory for multiple composers

Tags: php, composer-php

I am going to rewrite this question to be more clear. I have the following application structure:

```
applications/
   api/
      public/
      composer.json
   frontend/
      public/
      composer.json
   backend/
      public/
      composer.json
   common/
      vendor/
        ... composer libraries here
```

How can I make that every single application's composer install gets installed into `common/vendor`, so that way I can have the most up to date version of the library in wherever is used with just one `composer update`; while at the same time only load the libraries that are in the `composer.json` file of each application. So, when I include `vendor/autoload.php`, only the needed libraries are loaded.

EDIT: Edited the whole question. Please reread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create one bigger meta project that requires the API package, the frontend and the backend. You can define which directory should be used for placing dependencies for this meta project, and should be able to define for the special packages API, frontend and backend that they should go into their respective directories and not the common folder.

Updating that meta package will have to check more dependencies, but it is guaranteed that you either get the newest possible versions that conform to your version constraints (which may NOT install the newest version available if one of your packages requires a lower version). That way you would avoid installing dependencies that are not allowed for one of the projects, and you would be immediately notified if you attempt to install conflicting versions.

Note that I wouldn't recommend this at all. I would write a script, placing it at `applications/updatecomposer.sh` and add all the commands necessary to update each project individually. You gain all the flexibility that Composer is about, because essentially you want to have the central library installation of PEAR back. This central installation and the resulting inability to update any of the PEAR packages without risking to break something is one of the reasons that PEAR is considered dead.

Or think about any pre-Composer originating framework like Zend Framework 1. Having this installed in a central point that every application is using will effectively prevent you from ever updating it, if you are not prepared to also deal with incompatibilities in ALL your applications at the same time. Just an example: Updating from any ZF 1.11 to ZF 1.12 (the currently maintained up to date version) is a potentially backwards-incompatible change, because at least one abstract class (dealing with REST interfaces) got new abstract methods that have to be implemented.